# Including a ClassRef in QuickBooks InventoryTransferAddRq

Tags: xml, quickbooks

I am building an XML request to create a TransferInventoryAddRq between two InventorySites.  My team noticed in QuickBooks Desktop when manually creating Inventory Transfers there is a Class column on the GUI; however the XMLOps template does not have a corresponding field: https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbdesktop/docs/api-reference/qbdesktop/transferinventoryadd

Leaving this field blank in QBD does not prevent the transfer action, it does produce a modal for the user to confirm they do not want to set a class for the transfer. We want to ensure that our customers have the ability to set a Class should they want to to better emulate their experience in QBD from our service. How can I add a new field that is not included in the approved structure, or is there a better query action we could be taking?